# TypeError: this.state.followers.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am building a simple github user card generator that fetches user data and that of their followers from github api and display them on a user card. The followers data fetched returns an array of objects. To pass data to the followers component, i mapped over the fetched array but on compiling i get error message `TypeError: this.state.followers.map is not a function`. I initialized the followers state with an empty string. Please help what could be the problem? Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import githublogo from './githublogo.svg'
import UserCard from './components/userCard.js';
import Followers from './components/follower.js';
import ErrorPage from './components/errorPage.js';
import Navbar from './components/navbar.js';
import './App.css';



class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

     this.state = {
       user: {},
       followers: [],
       input: '',
       submit: '',
       userExists: null,
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleExistence = this.handleExistence.bind(this);
   }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://api.github.com/users/{this.state.submit}')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.setState({
         user: data
      });
   });

  fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/{this.state.submit}/followers`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.setState({
      followers: data
    });
  });
 }

 handleChange(e) {
   this.setState({
      input: e.target.value
   });
 }

 handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState(state => ({
      submit: state.input
    }));
 }

 handleExistence() {
   if (this.state.submit === this.state.user.login) {
     this.setState({
        userExists: true
     });
   }
   else {
     this.setState({
       userExists: false
     });
   }
 }

 render() {

const renderFollowers = this.state.followers.map((follower) => <Followers 
      avatar= {follower.avatar_url} 
      username= {follower.login}
      id= {follower.id}
      githubLink= {follower.html_url}
      darkMode= {this.state.darkMode}
    />);

return (
  <div> 
    <Navbar /> 
    <div>
      <header>
        <img src={githublogo} alt="logo" />
        <h1>Welcome to Github UserCard Generator</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.input} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Github Username" />
          <button type="submit" onClick={this.handleExistence}>Generate User Card</button>
        </form>
      </header>
    </div>
    {this.state.userExists ? <div>
      <UserCard
        avatar={this.state.user.avatar_url}
        name={this.state.user.name}
        username={this.state.user.login}
        location={this.state.user.location}
        publicRepos={this.state.user.public_repos}
        following={this.state.user.following}
        followers={this.state.user.followers}
        githubLink={this.state.user.html_url} 
      />
      {renderFollowers} 
    </div> : <ErrorPage /> }
  </div>

  );

  }
}
```

Comment: What does the `console.log(data)` show? It seems that the data coming back from the API isn't an array (presumably it's an object instead).

Comment: Are you certain your input is a valid github username?
fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/{this.state.submit}/followers`) 
will return an array IF provided with a valid github username. If it is not provided with a valid github username, the API returns an error message in the form of an object, in which case your map function will throw that error.

Comment: The data i get from my console for  `https://api.github.com/users/{this.state.submit}/followers`  is an array of objects.

Comment: Very weird, you initialize `this.state.followers = []`, so it should not throw this error. Can you do `console.log(this.state)` right before that call in `render` and add the output to your post?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check for errors, i.e., when a username does not exist: 
https://api.github.com/users/admin/followers

It should be as simple as checking that the result is an array:

```
fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/{this.state.submit}/followers`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    if (data instanceof Array)
        this.setState({
          followers: data
        });
  });
```